# Sample code to Draw routes Using Google Maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw a path between given start and end directions for my custom Map application.

Is there any library to draw routes (driving path) for Android native app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr="+latitude+","+longitude+"&daddr="+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude();
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw path in native app then this intent will help you

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+ String.valueOf(current_lattitude) +","+ String.valueOf(current_longitude) +"&daddr="+ String.valueOf(dest_lati) +","+ String.valueOf(dest_longi)));
                        startActivity(intent);
```